# how to solve $\frac{-1.8\cdot 10^{-10}}{x^2}+\left(2\cdot 10^{-5}\right)+\left(4\cdot 10^{-5}\right)x=0$

Tags: calculus

I want to solve the equation، first I tried to solve Directly but I couldn't because of really large numbers. so can I calculate Directly in simple way? 
I actually try to calculate by approximating using Newton Raphson method BUT I didn't have starting point so I start with [symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/calculus-calculator/%5Cfrac%7B-1.8%5Ccdot10%5E%7B-10%7D%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D%2B%5Cleft(2%5Ccdot10%5E%7B-5%7D%5Cright)%2B%5Cleft(4%5Ccdot10%5E%7B-5%7D%5Cright)x%3D0?or=input) to get hint but it couldn't be right thing to start with 0.00299 because $\frac{-1.8\cdot 10^{-10}}{x^2}+\left(2\cdot 10^{-5}\right)+\left(4\cdot 10^{-5}\right)x=0$ It does not get close to zero I just need to solve the equation in my chemistry problem and I need help.
Newton Raphson method:$x_{0}=0.00299$
$x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{\left(-1.8\cdot 10^{-10}+\left(2\cdot 10^{-5}\right)x_{n}^2+\left(4\cdot 10^{-5}\right)x_{n}^3\right)}{\left(4\cdot 10^{-5}x_{n}+12\cdot 10^{-5}x_{n}^2\right)}$

$x_{1}=0.002991067051$
$x_{2}=0.002991066859$ 
it's not the thing that symbolab said

Comment: Did you try some other on-line tool? For an instance WolframAlpha is quite good with Newton Raphson method...

Comment: If you found any of the responses below helpful, then please click the corresponding green check mark to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by multiplying the entire equation by $10^5 x^2$. Doing so yields:
$$-1.8\cdot 10^{-5} +2x^2 + 4x^3 = 0\tag{1} \label{1}$$
In this equation, the $-1.8\cdot 10^{-5}$ is basically negligible, so the approximate solutions are solved by $$2x^2+4x^3 = 0 \implies x^2(2+4x)=0 \implies x=0, x=-\frac{1}{2}.$$
If you require more precise answers, you can use the [cubic formula](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/) to solve the cubic equation above.
Alternatively, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-1.8*10%5E%28-5%29%20%2B2x%5E2%20%2B%204x%5E3%3D0) solves equation $\ref{1}$ as approximately
$$x=-0.499982, -0.003009, 0.002991.$$

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need help getting your equation

$$ \frac{-1.8\cdot 10^{-10}}{x^2}+\left(2\cdot 10^{-5}\right)+\left(4\cdot 10^{-5}\right)x=0 $$

in standard form. You could begin by converting negative exponents into positive exponents using the rule $a^{-n} = \frac{1}{a^n}$ as follows

$$ \frac{-1.8}{x^2 10^{10}} + \frac{2}{10^5} + \frac{4x}{10^5} = 0 $$

$$ \frac{-1.8}{x^2 10^{10}} + \frac{2}{10^5} \Big( \frac{x^2 10^5}{x^2 10^5} \Big) + \frac{4x}{10^5} \Big( \frac{x^2 10^5}{x^2 10^5} \Big) = 0 $$

$$ \frac{-1.8}{x^2 10^{10}} + \frac{2 x^2 10^5}{x^2 10^{10}} + \frac{4 x^3 10^5}{x^2 10^{10}} = 0 $$

$$ \frac{-1.8 + 2 x^2 10^5 + 4 x^3 10^5}{x^2 10^{10}} = 0 $$

$$ (x^2 10^{10}) \frac{-1.8 + 2 x^2 10^5 + 4 x^3 10^5}{x^2 10^{10}} = 0 (x^2 10^{10})$$

$$ -1.8 + 2 x^2 10^5 + 4 x^3 10^5 = 0 $$

$$ 4 x^3 10^5 + 2 x^2 10^5 - 1.8 = 0 $$

$$ (4 \cdot 10^5) x^3 + (2 \cdot 10^5) x^2 + 0x + (-1.8) = 0 $$

$$ 400000 x^3 + 200000 x^2 + 0x + (-1.8) = 0 $$

You now have a cubic equation in standard form where $a=400000 , b=200000, c=0, d=-1.8$, and you can solve for $x$ via the [cubic formula](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/) (also known as the Cardano method).

Note that all cubic equations will have either one real root or three real roots. For this reason, the Newton-Raphson method may not be the best means of finding the roots as it will converge on one and only one root closest to your initial value. So, if there are multiple roots, then you will have to reuse the method with different intial values, hoping you are "close enough" to the other roots to find them.

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(x)$ for the LHS of your equation.  Then $f^\prime(x) = \frac{3.6\times10^{-10}}{x^3} + 4\times10^{-5}$ and $f^{\prime\prime}(x) = -\frac{1.08\times10^{-9}}{x^4}$.

Setting the derivative equal to zero, we find a critical value at $x = \sqrt[3]{-9\times 10^{-6}} \approx -0.0208$.  (And of course there's the other critical value $x = 0$.)

Since $f^{\prime\prime}(x) < 0$ for all $x \ne 0$, we know that the nontrivial critical point is a local maximum.  Since $f(-0.0208) \approx 1.8752$, there will be two roots for negative values of $x$.  Maybe we can plug $x_0 = -0.0208 \pm \epsilon$ into Newton's method to find them?  Well, I'll get back to that :).

In any case, if $x > 0$, it is clear that $f^\prime(x) > 0 $.  Since $f(x)$ will be dominated by its $\frac{1}{x^2}$ term for $x$ in some neighborhood of zero, and by its $x$ term for, say, $x > 1$, we know from the Intermediate Value Theorem that there will be a root somewhere in $(0,1)$.  I would have hoped that it didn't matter which value from this interval you choose for $x_0$ here.  But...

It's been a long time since I've used Newton's method; I admit that I had to look it up.  One thing I do remember about it, though, is that it doesn't always work.  Here, for example, it looks as though if I pick an initial value from $(0,1)$, I get the root near $x=-1/2$.  Which isn't what you want to happen.  That seems to be the only one I find.

What you do know, though, is that you have one root a bit less than $x = -0.0208$, another in $(-0.0208,0)$ and a third in $(0,1)$.  If nothing else, a [bisection search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) should find good approximations of the roots fairly quickly.